# Proof that $K^*(BG)=K^*(BT)^W$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory, k-theory

I was wondering if anyone had a refrence for the fact that $K^*(BG)=K^*(BT)^W$ for $G$ a compact connected lie group, $T$ a maximal torus, and $W$ the associated Lie group. I was able to derive this fact from the corrosponding fact for the representation ring, using the Atiyah-Segal completion theorem. Does anyone have a proof of this fact that doesn't involve Atiyah-Segal?

Comment: You mean $K^{\bullet}(BT)^W = K^{\bullet}(BG)$. Related, but not quite an answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167655/whats-the-relationship-between-these-two-isomorphisms-involving-g-and-t

Comment: @Qiaochu Of course, this has been corrected.